# Prove the uniform convergence of the next series.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Prove the uniform convergence of the next series.

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n}}{n^{2}}$ in the interval $\left[-1,1\right]$

We know, $f(x)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{x^{n}}{n^{2}}=0.$

Then, exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that if $n\geq N$ then

$$|\frac{x^{n}}{n^{2}}-0|=|\frac{x^{n}}{n^{2}}|\leq\frac{x^{n}}{N^{2}}...$$

How i can bound $x^{n}$ for prove uniformly convergence of that series ?

Other way, i was think About the Weiestrass M Test, i trying to bound this:

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n}}{n^{2}}\leq\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{2}}$

How the last serie converge then by Weiestrass M test, the serie $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n}}{n^{2}}$ is uniformly convergent.

Comment: Well, $x \in [-1, 1]$, which gives you a pretty strong bound on $x^n$

Comment: Yea @AsafHaas HAHA, i dont see that, is 1.

Comment: Your use of the Weierstrass M Test is good, except that the requirement is $\frac {x^2} {n^2} \le \frac 1 {n^2}$, without sums.

Comment: Thanks @AsafHaas for the correction.